# wordpress demo theme customization

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

https://selademo.wordpress.com/

I want the above layout for my website and i have the demo version of this theme which has some limited layout. How easily i can extend this demo theme to be like the original theme . Basically i want to customize theme.

I tried with Theme matcher but it is not working.

is there any tool available? . Or is there any easy way to develop the new theme by copying the code of the premium theme?.

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Buy the theme. 2. Roll your own. 3. Questions like this are against SO rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can customize your theme without knowing php,html etc...

If you know CSS and Html just fallow the two steps

- Open the child theme style.css file in your text editor. (Or skip the
  FTP and text editor and just go to your WordPress admin area,
  Appearance => Editor, and click on style.css on the right side).
- Open your site in Google Chrome, and open the Dev Tools (right-click
  and select “inspect element”).

If you dont aware about php, html, css etc. Follow the  below link

[click me to customize wordpress](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/wordpress/customize-theme.htm#customize)

And Most of the Theme having Theme documentation you should follow the steps inside the theme documentation to change by theme options.

Answer (score 0):

Before using the tool, you should learn about PHP, HTML, CSS, javascript.

After learning these things, you should learn Wordpress basic like block, functions.

Then you can make your own theme and remake other's theme.

Comment: I know CSS PHP and HTML JS and basics of wordpress.My question is , any tool available or what are the suggested ideas?